# inserting li element after a selected li by text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following list:

```
<ol id="mainlist">
<li>Item1
    <ol>
        <li>SubItem1</li>
        <li>SubItem2</li>
        <li>SubItem3</li>
    </ol>
</li>
<li>Item2
    <ol>
        <li>SubItem1</li>
        <li>SubItem2</li>
        <li>SubItem3</li>
    </ol>
</li>
<li>Item3
    <ol>
        <li>SubItem1</li>
        <li>SubItem2</li>
        <li>SubItem3</li>
    </ol>
</li>
</ol>

<span>Add text</span><input type="text" /><span>, after the element </span> <input type="text" /><input type="button" value="Add" />
```

I have two text inputs. The first one is where the user is supposed to write the text that he/she wants to insert after the element specified in the second text input box.

The problem is that I don't know how to select the correct `li` based on its text.

I've tried the following using jQuery:

```
$('input[type="button"]').on('click',function(){
    $item=$('<li>',{
        html:$('input')[0].value
    });
    $position=$('input')[1];

    $('li:contains("'+$position.value+'")').filter(function() {
          return $(this).text() == $position.value;
    }).after($item);
});
```

But that doesn't work. I don't know how to select the item where I am going to insert the object `<li>`.

Comment: Let's say, the user is entering 'SubItem3' in second textbox, where should the value in first textbox be inserted?

Comment: You wrote `$posicion.value` in line 8 instead of `$position.value`

Comment: And your `$item` and `$position` variables are declared outside of the function, yes?

Comment: why are you using `':contains'` selector as well as `filter()` ?

Comment: sorry, I have translated the names of the variables into English to make it easier and I missed the variable name '$posicion'. On the other hand, why should I declare the variables outside the function??. It doesnt give me any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've cleaned up your code and had to make a slight amendment to make it work properly.

One problem you had was that your structure was `<ol><li><ol><li>` which meant that any searching for `li` elements or even `ol li` elements meant it appends to both the parent and child which doesn't seem to be what you want to achieve.

Hope this is what you were trying to achieve.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="button"]').on('click', function() {
    var item = $('<li>', {
      html: $('input')[0].value
    });
    var position = $('input')[1].value;

    $('ol li').each(function() {
      var firstWord = $(this).text().substr(0, $(this).text().indexOf(" "));
      if (firstWord.trim() == position) {
        $(this).after(item);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol id="mainlist">
  <li>Item1
    <ol>
      <li>SubItem1</li>
      <li>SubItem2</li>
      <li>SubItem3</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Item2
    <ol>
      <li>SubItem1</li>
      <li>SubItem2</li>
      <li>SubItem3</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Item3
    <ol>
      <li>SubItem1</li>
      <li>SubItem2</li>
      <li>SubItem3</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>

<span>Add text</span>
<input type="text" /><span>, after the element </span>
<input type="text" />
<input type="button" value="Add" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is not really what I am looking for. I dont want to insert an <li> element after a position given with a number. What I would like is given a name of an Item, insert after it a new <li> element.

Comment: No, just only after Item2. I think your code is close, I have been trying replacing 'nth-child' for 'contains', but still doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you used `.value` to get the input value in jQuery. However, `.value` belongs to javascript. Since you are using jquery, you need to  use `.val()`.

I worked on an example: https://jsfiddle.net/6r18ag68/2/

```
$('input[type="button"]').on('click',function(){
    var newitem = $('<li>' + $('#txt1').val() + '</li>');

    $('li').filter(function () {
        return $(this).text() == $('#txt2').val();
    }).after(newitem);

    $('#mainlist > li').filter(
          function(){ 
             return $.trim($(this).html().split('<')[0]) == $('#txt2').val(); }).append(newitem);
    });
});
```

Comment: It doesnt work your code, the element <li> is inserted after all the <li> elements

Comment: @galeonweb I was not clear about this. How should we determine the specific <li> item if they have multiple matching <li> items

Comment: That is the problem. You have two text boxs, in one of them you write the text you want to insert and in the other you write the text to match with one of your li items from your list. In your code you use ':contains()' but it doesnt make an exact text match

Comment: it may match multiple items, we need to decide add after which one? how do you prefer it to work?

Comment: It is an exercise for the university. It is just that, to insert an item after another item. But the position is not given, so that you use the text content. For example, if I say 'Item3', then the new element is inserted just after 'Item3'

Comment: Then if you say subitem3 then the new item will be inserted after each of them, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

1. You should declare variables such as `$item` with `var`, unless you want them to be put on an enclosing scope
2. The statement, `return $(this).text() == $posicion.value;`, has "position" misspelled
3. Some `li` nodes are identical in your example. I assume you need a way to differentiate them by ancestor `li` element. That means you need three inputs

How about this?

```
$('input[type="button"]').on('click',function(){
    var newText = $('input#newText').val();
    var ancestorLiText = $('input#ancestorLiText').val();
    var liText = $('input#liText').val();

    var $ancestorEl = $('ol#mainlist').find('li').filter(function (i) {
        return $(this).text() === ancestorLiText;
    });
    var $el = $ancestorEl.find('li').filter(function (i) {
        return $(this).text() === liText;
    });
    var $newLi = $('<li>').text(newText);
    $el.after($newLi);
});
```

You should be able to derive what HTML you need from this code (you'll need inputs with IDs "newText", "ancestorLiText", and "liText")

Also, note that the `:contains()` selector is like a global search on an element's text. Therefore a search for `li:contains(chair)` would match both `<li>chair</li>` and `<li>not a chair</li>`.